# Sudo chmod +x leads to "cannot access [file] permission denied"

Tags: installation, matlab

I'm trying to install Matlab using super user privileges. The reason I want to do this is because the installer is unable to create folders, which is necessary.

Nothing happens when I do

```
sudo install -v
```

And when I try

```
chmod +x install
```

I get

```
chmod: cannot access 'install': Permission denied
```

The output of

```
ls -la install
```

is

```
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 24293 Jan 16  2013 install
```

I don't know if this is relevant, but I am trying to install from a mounted image.

Comment: Can you do a `sudo chmod +x install`?

Comment: which is it? either the title is wrong or the body: you claim sudo in the title leads to a permission denied. And is seriously doubt that to be the case.

Comment: Try `sudo bash install` to run a your install script in a shell. If you just `sudo install` you're running the `install` command which is most likely not what you want. Also, you say "nothing happens", is this true (as in absolutely nothing happens) or do you get a message or an error? (The `install` command will say `install: missing file operand`).

Comment: @Rinzwind that's why I'm stuck. I tried doing it as root and am getting similar problems.

Comment: @roadmr I do that and I get   bash: install: Permission denied

Comment: @roadmr I get the error "install: missing file operand" like you said.

Comment: Can you show permissions of your `install` file? Add to your question the output of `ls -la install`. Thanks!

Comment: @Jobin I get "chmod: cannot access 'install': Permission denied

Comment: @roadmr -r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 24293 Jan 16 2013 install

Comment: The image may be read-only, explaining why you can't change the permissions. Copy everything in your image to a directory in /tmp, then change to that directory, change install's permissons to 755 (`sudo chmod 755 install`), and try to run it first without sudo (`./install`, don't forget the dot at the beginning so that you don't invoke the system command instead).

Comment: @roadmr Thanks for the help. Waiting for the copy to finish and will let you know what happens.

Comment: @roadmr Worked. Had to do sudo ./install after changing the permissions. Thanks. Wish I could give you the checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image turned out to be read-only, explaining why you can't change the permissions.

Copy everything in your image to a directory in /tmp, then change to that directory, change install's permissons to 755 (sudo chmod 755 install), and try to run it first without sudo (./install, don't forget the dot at the beginning so that you don't invoke the system command instead).