# Sudo chmod gets permissions denied

Tags: permissions

When I run `ls -l`, the file I want to change permissions of is:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 82176 1491 193716029663 Feb 16  2019 cfdna_hc_bam.bam
```

First try: `chmod 775 cfdna_hc_bam.bam`.
Result: `chmod: changing permissions of 'cfdna_hc_bam.bam': Permission denied`

Second try: `sudo chmod 775 cfdna_hc_bam.bam`. It asks for my password, I provide it and the Results: `chmod: cannot access 'cfdna_hc_bam.bam': Permission denied`.

When I enter `cd ..`, `ls -l`, to see the permissions on the directory in which my file is, this is the result: `drwxrwsr-x 1 93501 1491    8192 Sep 28 14:24  bam_files`.

The only question I found similar is ([Sudo chmod +x leads to "cannot access [file] permission denied"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409327/sudo-chmod-x-leads-to-cannot-access-file-permission-denied)), and it had to do with a mounted image problem, which isn't my case here.

**EDIT**:

- I created a file in this directory, and changed its permissions, and
  it worked:

  ```
  touch a
  chmod 755 a
  ```

  This works.
- Then I did the same thing using 'sudo', and it didnt:

  ```
  touch a
  sudo chmod 755 a I get: `chmod: cannot access 'a': Permission denied`.
  ```
- Also, when I run the command `id` I get:

  ```
  uid=1004(yonatan) gid=1005(yonatan) groups=1005(yonatan),27(sudo),132(docker)
  ```
- Trying to run `sudo chown yonatan:yonatan -R <dir>` on the directory in which the file is (and also in above directories), results in: `chown: cannot access 'bam_files': Permission denied`.

Comment: i do not know if this will work out but can you try `sudo chmod ug+rwx,o+rx` ? it is the same as what you did but i dont know.. also can you try log as root and then run the same command?

Comment: The files may be on a filesystem that doesn't support permissions (FAT32), or the filesystem is mounted as read only. Some background info is needed to verify. Also, you may still try and copy the files to /tmp, it should help, I suspect.

Comment: As for @johncli , I ran your command and I get a similar output.

Comment: @mikewhatever  - I am running on a remote Ubuntu 18.04 machine. In the past I ran chmod on this machine. This is a 200Gb file, so I don't have any space left to copy it to. As for the file system - I don't exactly understand what you mean (new to linux). What command do I use to reveal the information on the filesystem?

Comment: can you try and create another file in the same directory and try to change his permissions (if its not working) try to create the same file outside of the directory and then change his permissions.  then we can understand if the problem is in directory permissions or specific file permissions.

Comment: @johncli  I did so, and it worked, but only when I don't use sudo, which is very weird (I think). See my edit.

Comment: @johncli I added the `id` command output. I'm admit I have no idea what the numbers mean (I am  new to linux). If it is relevant, this is a machine that I connect to remotely. The file was transferred to me by another person, I think through `sshfs` but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @johncli The function unfortunately does not output anything. However, when I run just `getent passwd`, I get a long sequence of outputs. I copied it to a test editor and ctrl+F'd for "1491" and "93501" but nothing is found.

Comment: @johncli Unfortunately this doesn't work, see my edit :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113681/discussion-between-johncli-and--).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The directory was received from another user on the remote machine.
2. You are not the owner of that machine so i suspect that the directory is "secured" from sudo command.
3. Try to contact the user that you received the directory from and the root of the remote machine and ask them to run this commands:

   - `chown -R yonatan:yonatan <filename>` or `chown -R 1004:1005 <filename>` (wich is the same command).
   - if the root run the command he can run it directly on the file you have received.
   - if the user that sent you the directory running the commands he needs to run that on a copy in his own "home file" and then sent it to you with your uid and gid permissions.
4. After you will be the owner of the directory try to run again the `chmod` command with the permissions you want.

   - for an example `chmod 775 <filename>`
5. **Remarks:**

   - in your own specific case 93501 is the user that own the directory and 1491 is the group that own the directory.
   - another option for a solution is to add your own user to 1491 (by the root), but then if other group 1491 users have access to your directory they will still have permissions to the file.
   - i recommend to use this calculator as "permissions calculator" http://permissions-calculator.org/
   - **if the following answer is failing to solve the problem please let me know on the comments so we can keep try to solve that out**.

Comment: I contacted the original owner of the files, who transferred them to me using sshfs. He tried to do chown, but it didn't work. I removed and sshfs'd the files again, and now their came to be with good permissions, so that is solved. I am experiencing related issues using docker and volume binding, but I opened a separate issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64193370/how-to-bind-volumes-that-were-sshfsd-with-the-right-permissions). Thanks for your help!